# Error in shared_preferences package flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am calling the shared_preferences: ^2.2.2 in flutter but keep having the following error:

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: package io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
                                                                             ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does it persist after `flutter clean`?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh yes even if i created a new flutter project and only added shared_preferences package, i got the same error when running it on android devices

Comment: I think you can with updating your dependencies+sdk version